# Deleting Lines after reading them in C++ program using system()

Tags: c++, bash, sed

I am trying to understand how basic I/O with files is handled in c++ or c. My aim is to read file line by line and send the lines across to a remote server. If the line is sent, I want to delete it from the file. 
One way I tried was that I kept a count of the lines read and called an `system()` system call to delete the 'count' number of lines. I used the bash command: `sed -i -e 1,'count'd filename`.
After that I continued reading the file and surprisingly it worked as planned.
I have two questions:

1. Is this way reliable?
2. And why does this work at all, when while
   reading the file I deleted a part of it and yet it works? What if I
   did a seek to a previous position, what then?

Best,Digvijay

PS: 
I would be glad if somebody could suggest a better way.

Also here is the code for the program I wrote:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>

int main(){
    std::ifstream f;
    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss;
    int i=0;
    f.open("in.txt");
    if(f.is_open()){
        while(getline(f,line)){
            std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
            i++;
            if(i==2)break;
        }
        ss<<"sed -i -e 1,"<<i<<"d in.txt";
        system(ss.str().c_str());
        while(getline(f,line)){
            std::cout<<line<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**
Firstly thanks for taking the time to write answers. But here is some extra information which I missed out on earlier.
 The files I am dealing with are log files. So they are constantly being appended with information from devices. The reason why I want to avoid creating a copy is, because the log file themselves are very big(at times) and plus this would help to keep the log file short. Since they would be divided into parts and archived on the server.
**Solution**
I have found the way to deal with the problem. Apparently Thomas is right, that sed does create a new file. So the old file remains as is. Using this, I can read n lines, call the system function, close the file pointer and open it again. I do this on small chunks of the log, repeatedly until it becomes small and hence efficient to deal with. The server while archives the logs in 1gb files.
However I have a new question, due to memory constraint, I need to know if it is possible to split a log file into two efficiently. (Which possibly would be another question on SO)

Comment: make another temporary file and copy the lines which you don't want to delete.

Comment: @sujin Making a copy is my last resort TBH. This file is actually a log file, of the size 3.7 GB at an instance. And there is one more complication, which I will mention in the edit.

Comment: Do you *read*, then *delete* each line from the start of your log? Do you process the entire log? If not, do you process every *line*? How do you determine "if the line has been sent"? Why would you seek to a previous position? On topic: keep both a Read pointer and a Write pointer. Read, then if the line would not need discarding, write. Repeat until end of file.

Comment: @Jongware No, not read and delete. (I haven't actually implemented on the log as of now.) I instead made up the dummy program above for dummy input. But in essence it would work the same: It would read say n lines, send it across and wait for it to be a success(blocking operation), then I would delete n lines from the beginning of the file, reset i and repeat. But yes I will not seek to a previous position. Also how do you discard a line? I mean I can overwrite it, but that's all(i think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed writes a new version of the file, while the program keeps reading the same version that it opened. This is the usual behavior of Unix and Linux when a program writes a file that another program has open.

You can see this for yourself with this small C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    while (1) {
        rewind(f);
        int lines = 0;
        int c;
        while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF)
            if (c == '\n')
                ++lines;
        printf("Number of lines in file: %d\n", lines);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run that program in one window, and then use sed in another window to edit the file. The number of lines printed by the program will stay the same, even if the file on disk has been edited, and this is because Unix keeps the old, open version, even if it is no longer accessible to other programs.

As to your first question, how reliable your solution is, as far as I can see it should be reliable, except with the usual caveats about the system crashing or running out of memory in the middle of an update, someone else accessing the file, and of course all the problems with the **system** call. It is not very efficient, though, and for large data sets you might want to do it differently.

sujin's comment about using a temporary file for the lines you want to keep seems reasonable. It would be both faster and safer. Keep the original file, so if the system crashes you'll still have your data, and wait until you have finished to rename the old file to "in.txt.bak", and then rename your temporary file to "in.txt".

Comment: From [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-do-i-delete-the-first-n-lines-of-an-ascii-file-using-shell-commands) I got to know that using -i operator sed does it in place, without creating a temp file.

Comment: Could you, update your answer with when '-i' operator is used. Much appreciated.

Comment: @digvijay91: The -i operator just creates a new file with the same name, but it is still a copy. The other program will still not see sed's changes.

Comment: but then how is that in-place? From the man-pages `edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)`

Comment: Turns out you are right. I seeked to the beginning, and it did show all the 'deleted' lines. This clears many things. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern file systems don't support deleting lines at the beginning of the file, so doing so would be very inefficient.

The normal solution to your actual problem is to stop writing to your log file when it reaches some size, then start writing to a new file. The code that copies the files can delete a whole file once it has been written (this is an efficient operation).

Answer (score 0):

First off, avoid use of `system` calls as much as you can (if possible, don't use it at all) as they create race conditions and other problems which drastically (and often) [detrimentally affect the outcome of your program](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/). This especially true if access to files are involved.

Given your problem, there are a number of ways to do this, each with its own caveats.

I'll cover three possible solutions:

1) If the file is small enough:

1. you can read in the entire thing in a data structure (vector, list, deque, etc.)
2. delete the original file
3. determine how many lines to read (and send off via server protocol)
4. then write the remaining lines as the name of the original file.

If you intend to parallelize your program later on, this may be a better solution, *provided that the file is small*. Note: small is a relative term, but is generally limited by how much memory you have available.

2) If the file is quite large or you're limited by memory constraints, you will have to get creative by using buffers. Once you've read a line and successfully sent it off via your program, you determine where the file pointer is and copy the remaining information until the end of the current file as a new file. Once done, close and delete the old file, then close and rename the new file the same name as the old file.

3) If your solution doesn't have to be in C++, you can use shell-scripting or (controversially) *another language* to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, it's not reliable.

2) The C++ runtime library reads your file in blocks (internally) which are then parceled out to your (higher level) input requests until the block(s) is(are) exhausted, forcing it to (internally) read more blocks from disk. Since one or more physical blocks are read in before you make any call to `sed`, it/they cannot be altered if `sed` happens to change that first part of the file.

To see your code fail, you would need to make the input file big enough that there are remaining blocks of the file that have not been read in (internally by the runtime library) before you call `sed`. By "fail" I mean your program would not see all the characters that were originally in the file before `sed` clobbered some lines.

Comment: Actually, this hasn't got anything to do with blocks in the runtime library. sed writes a new version of the file, while the program keeps reading the same version that it opened. This is the usual behavior of Unix and Linux when a program writes a file that another program has open.

Answer (score -1):

As the other guys said, you have to make another file with the records you need after read the original file and then delete it. But in this application perhaps you will see more useful a fifo than a file. If you are on a *NIX platform check up about the makefifo statement from the console.

It is like a file with the singularity that after read a line it gets deleted.

Comment: I don't quite see how a fifo would be useful here?

Comment: Because he would need less logic into the program.